# Is it possible to define a dependency between two beans in Spring outside of the definition of the two beans?

Tags: java, spring

I use the [`depends-on`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson) attribute in our production system to control the shutdown order of the beans. Thus, `Bean1` doesn't have a compile-time dependency on `Bean2`, but it should be shutdown first to ensure correct operation. I'd like to test `Bean1` in isolation by injecting it into my unit tests. Because `Bean2` isn't part of the test, I don't want it to be loaded by Spring when I run the test. Is it possible to express this dependency outside of the definition of `Bean1` and `Bean2`?

The hacky solution I've come up with is to simply define a dummy `Bean2` in my test context, which will be loaded to satisfy the dependency, but I'd like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define Bean1 in it's own application context file. Include this file in the main application context like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-bean1.xml" />
```

Now, create two almost identical files named "applicationContext-bean1.xml". Store one in your main application directory, and the other one in a `test` directory. Don't put `depends-on` in the file in the `test` directory. Then, when you run your test, make sure the classpath include the `test` directory before the main directory.

I don't know if this is a more elegant solution, but it is another way of addressing the problem. :)